# Convert latitude/longitide to pixel in geotif

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I have two different `geotiff` files, one for Spain and the other for the Europe.

I selected an area in the `geotiff` of Spain. What I have to do is to find its correspondence in the `geotiff` of Europe.

I changed `geotiff` into `numy` array. I would like to know given the pixel `x_min`, `y_min`, `x_max`, `y_max` in the array of data from Spain, how can i find the correspondent `x_min`, `y_min`, `x_max`, `y_max` of the same area in the array of Europe. I know `gdal.GetGeoTranform()` can be used to do this, but how?

Thanks

Comment: What do you know about the spatial reference of your geotiff files ? You have to look after this spatial reference.

Comment: Hi, geotif of spain is 5m and for the europe is 20m.

Comment: This is not the spatial reference but the size of the cells... Do you know about the Spatial reference System ? [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system). You have first to know if the two files have the same spatial reference before working directly with the cells.